# C# MVC3 and non-latin characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have my database results (áéíóúàâêô...) and when I display any of this characters I get codes like:

```
&#225;
```

My controller is like this:

```
ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma = (from e in db.EstadosDeAlma select e.Title).ToList();
```

My cshtml page is like this:

```
var data = '@foreach (dynamic item in ViewBag.EstadosDeAlma){ @(item + " ") }';
```

In addition, if I use any rich text editor as Tiny MCE all non-latin characters are like this too.

What should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: &#225; is the correct encoding for the accented a character, and it should render OK on the page. Are you seeing the &#225; on the page rendered to the user or when you view source in your browser?

Comment: I´m using that with jquery autocomplete, so when I try to find the portuguese word "ágil" I can´t, cuz actually is written &#225;gil in the html code...

Answer (score 0):

What output encoding are you using on your web pages? I would suggest using UTF-8 since you want a lot of non-ascii characters to work.

Comment: Yes. That would be in you "master page" (Layout file, viewstart, etc, I don't know where you have your HTML head section). And of course you need to ensure that the characters are returned correctly from the database to your .net app too...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should HTML encode/decode the values before comparing them.

Since you are using jQuery you can take advantage of the encoding functions built-in into it. For example:

```
$('<div/>').html('& #225;gil').html()
```

gives you "ágil" (notice that I added an extra space between the & and the # so that stackoverflow does not encode it, you won't need it)

This other question has more information about this. 
[HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)